# Scala: How to write generic function on sortable collection with arithmetic elements

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following Scala function,

```
def isValid(xs: Array[Int]): Boolean = {
  val List(x, y, z) = xs.sorted.toList
  x + y > z
}
```

and this still works when I change the input type to `List[Double]`.  What I would like is for this to work with generic collections, and on any elements that can be compared and added.

EDIT: This is what I have currently that is more generic.  Unfortunately, it requires that I specify the generic parameters.

```
def isValid[N, S <% Seq[N]](xs: S)(implicit n: Numeric[N]): Boolean = {
  val Seq(x, y, z) = xs.sorted
  n.gt(n.plus(x, y), z)
}

// Ideally, I wouldn't have to specify the generic parameters.
listOfArray.filter(isValid[Int, Array[Int]])
listOfList.filter(isValid[Double, List[Double]])
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"work with generic collections"*? `Array[T]` is a generic collection.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I meant that I'd like to parameterize over the container itself, and not just the elements of the container, e.g. I'd like this to work with both `Array` and `List` as well as other containers if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Numeric`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html)s:

- it extends [`Ordering`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html), so you can call `.sorted` on your collection
- it implements the `.plus` and `.gt` operators

Usage:

```
scala> def isValid[N](xs: Seq[N])(implicit ev: Numeric[N]): Boolean = {
         val x::y::z::Nil = xs.sorted.toList
         ev.gt(ev.plus(x, y), z)  // same as 'x + y > z'
       }
isValid: [N](xs: Seq[N])(implicit ev: Numeric[N])Boolean
```

Then:

```
scala> isValid(List(1, 2, 3))
res0: Boolean = false

scala> isValid(List(1d, 2d, 3d))
res1: Boolean = false

scala> isValid(List(1L, 2L, 2L))
res2: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I see.  I was still trying `x + y > z` instead of  using the methods from `ev`.

This gets me closer to what I was looking for, but I still would like to call it with both a `List` or an `Array` and it doesn't look like there's an implicit conversion from `Array` to `Seq`.   Maybe I can provide one though.  Lemme try.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted` is declared in `SeqLike` so you can require just `Seq`:

```
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  import Ordering.Implicits._

  def isValid[N: Numeric](xs: Seq[N]): Boolean = {
    val Seq(x, y, z) = xs.sorted
    x + y > z
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case I get

    error: type mismatch;
      found   : N
      required: String
        x + y > z
            ^
    one error found

Comment: @did you include both `import`s from my example in your code?